# Amchart Legend Position is not changing

Tags: javascript, css, amcharts

I face the probleme of the size of the chart when there is a big legend , and i found this article [Putting a legend outside the chart area](https://amcharts.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203002542-Putting-a-legend-outside-the-chart-area)
the probleme with this solution is that i can't put the legend on the top or the left or the even the right sideof the Chart , it is always stuck in the bottom. any ideas how to solve this.

Here is an example of what i want to do

JS file
`

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "startDuration": 0,
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "legend": {
    "divId" : "legenddiv",

  },
  "innerRadius": "30%",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }, {
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  }],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country"
});

var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
legend.position = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
 chart.addLegend(legend, "legenddiv");
```

`

html file

```
  <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>top</option>
  <option>left</option>
  <option>right</option>
  <option>Bottom</option>
</select>
Chart div:
<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 250px; border: 2px dotted #c33; margin: 5px 0 20px 0;"></div>

<br />
Legend div:
<div id="legenddiv" style="border: 2px dotted #3f3; margin: 5px 0 20px 0;"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXbjrJ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tried seriously? If you look at the example just by changing the order of the div you have the legend on top: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/Cww3D/
and with some basic CSS can put right or left

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but my probleme here is that the position change according to a input  it's not static, so i can't juste change that by putting the div on the top, that's not a solution in my case

Comment: Can you put your code here?

Answer (score 0):

I used the example of the first link you post, is already in jsfiddle and is better for use here.

Changing the class of div#container (top, bottom, right and left) legend is positioned into place. Could be associated a javascript event to select  to change the class but that I have not done. I hope you understand my horrible English .

http://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/4L0865Lv/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="right">
  <div class="chart">
    Chart div:
    <div id="chartdiv" style="height: 250px; border: 2px dotted #c33; margin: 5px 0 20px 0;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="legend">
    Legend div:
    <div id="legenddiv" style="border: 2px dotted #3f3; margin: 5px 0 20px 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 15px;
}

#legenddiv {
  height: 100px !important;
  /* force that height */
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
}

#container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top .legend {
  order: -1
}

.bottom {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom .chart {
  order: 1;
}

.right,
.left {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.right > div,
.left > div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.left .legend {
  order: -1;
}

.right #legenddiv,
.left #legenddiv {
  height: 250px !important;
}
```